# Merge [docusign] and [docusignapi]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It sounds like [docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusign) and [docusignapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi) are the same thing.

Can we merge the tags [docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusign) and [docusignapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi)?

Answer (score 14):

This does seem like a good idea, in fact 1.5k/1.8k questions in [docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusign) already has the [docusignapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi) tag. However, given that DocuSign is a product, we probably need to clean up the tag before merging.

There are 298 questions in [docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusign) that don't have [docusignapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi) tag. We don't need to go through all of these. We can just check the ones which *probably* are just about the using the product as such, which would be off topic.

There are [exactly 100 questions in the [docusign] tag that are not positively scored, don't have any code bits in them, or any API related characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocusign%5D+-%5Bdocusignapi%5D+-%5Bapi%5D+is%3Aq+-%22API%22+-%22Request%22+score%3A..0+hascode%3A0+closed%3A0&mixed=0). We need to just skim through these 2 pages of question excerpts, to make sure that they aren't off-topic.

Once that is done, we can merge and synonymize the [docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusign) and the [docusignapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi) tags.

Update: I went thorugh those 100 questions. Seems like most was related to the API. There were 8 of them that were clearly about the webapp usage, which I closed as General Computing and deleted. I have now merged and syn'd the tags.